# Constant prompting for user credentials

Tags: login

Once I log in to my site and go to a sub-site, even though I'm a member of the sub-site, I'm asked to provide my credentials again...The site contains about 10 sub-sites and the prompts do nhot occur on some of the sites...Is this a common issue?

Steve

Comment: Are the subsites using any custom branding/scripts/master pages?

Comment: Are you using multiple servers and load balancing?

Answer (score 1):

Is your site added to local intranet??

does it have anonymous access enabled?? if it's a publishing site then you have to approve all the pending items??

Check in fiddler for any 401s

Answer (score 0):

[Disable loopback check with powershell](http://sptwentyten.wordpress.com/2010/03/06/disable-the-loopback-check-via-powershell/)

[Some additional details](http://www.harbar.net/archive/2009/07/02/disableloopbackcheck-amp-sharepoint-what-every-admin-and-developer-should-know.aspx)

Comment: Blanketly saying it's a loop back issue when it's an intermittant issue isn't very helpful.

Comment: I mis-read the last sentence. I thought he said it does occur on the others.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a publishing site? I have seen the constant challenging occurs if there is a mix of draft/checkedout/published/approved status pages.